# Trigger on insert for a specific colum SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, triggers, insert

I am trying to make and update in different tables when and insert comes in the main table,i want to do this when the payment comes from paypal, so in that colum we can read Paypal or Visa.

```
Table1transactions
OrderID PaymentType  Name   LastName 
1       Paypal       NULL    NULL
2       Visa         Jhon    Mercury

Table2orders Main Table
OrderID CustomerID Payment Type
1         1001       Paypal
2         2002       Visa

Table3users
CustomerID   Name    Lastname
1001         Quenn   AC/DC
1002         Jhon    Mercury
```

The RDBMS is SQL SERVER on Windows.

I will try to explain it better:

When one guy buy something with Paypal this creates a row in table2 but it doesn't populate the name and more details on a table1 that we need to manage the orders, this doesn't happen with the visa inserts because is diferent proccess, so i created a SQL statement to update the table1 and syncronyze with the data on table 3 and now we can see the order details for Paypal customers.
I want to create a Trigger on table2 for each row inserted, I do not know if you can create a validating tigrer who reads for the new row if Table2.PaymentType='Paypal' execute update table1 .......
else nothing......

Do you have an idea how or which is the best way do to this? at the moment i am running the update manually but i want to find a solution like a schedule or a trigger.

Hope now is easy for undesrtand. Sorry about my english, is not the best...

Thanks for that!

Comment: your post is definitely missing the bare minimum information required to help you. no detail about the data structures involved and you didn't even mention the rdbms.

Comment: I changed the explication, hope that helps, sorry i am new here and my english is not the best :S

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER INSERT
   ON table_name FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   -- variable declarations

   -- trigger code

END;
```

Comment: Thanks for that Tarun, But i knew to do that, the thing that i don't know how to do is how i filter the paymentType to only make the update.
At the moment i have something like this:update table1 set name lastaname where table1.orderid=table2orderid and table2.customerid=table3.customerid and table2.paymenttype='Paypal'

So i want to filter in the triger something like, if paymenttype='Paypal' update........  [ else] dont do nothing. This is the thing that i don't know how to do  it. May you give a help on this?

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER INSERT
   ON table_name FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   -- variable declarations

   -- trigger code

END;
```